# Fourier transform of random variables

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, greens-functions, second-quantization, randomness

My question is concerning Fourier transforms of random variables. So if the question itself is too heavy a task but you know of any good resources to learn this topic that would also be very much appreciated.

Let's say I have a lattice of identical non-interacting point dipoles (modelling an array of nanoparticles). The Hamiltonian reads

$$H_0=\sum_\mathbf{R} \left( \frac{\Pi^2(\mathbf{R})}{2M} + \frac{1}{2}M\omega_0^2h^2(\mathbf{R}) \right)$$

where $h(\mathbf{R})$ and $\Pi(\mathbf{R})$ are the displacement of the electronic centre of mass and its conjugate momentum of a dipole at location $\mathbf{R}$ respectively.

What if I allow $\omega_0$ (the natural frequency of oscillation of the dipoles) to have a random distribution of values such that $\omega_0 \rightarrow \omega_0(1+\eta(\mathbf{R}))$ where $\eta$ is some random variable with a distribution such that it is always small compared to 1.

How do I perform a Fourier transform into wave-vector/momentum space so that I can find the dispersion and other physical properties of this system?

I treat the problem up to the point where I get stuck:

Keeping only first order terms in $\eta$ the Hamiltonian now reads

$$H=H_0 + \sum_\mathbf{R} M\omega_0^2 \eta(\mathbf{R}) h^2(\mathbf{R}).$$

Introducing the bosonic operators

$$a_\mathbf{R} = \sqrt{\frac{M\omega_0}{2\hbar}}h(\mathbf{R})+i\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\hbar M\omega_0}}\Pi(\mathbf{R})$$

and its conjugate the Hamiltonian becomes

$$H=H_0 + \frac{\hbar\omega_0}{2}\sum_\mathbf{R}\eta(\mathbf{R})(a_\mathbf{R}+a_\mathbf{R}^\dagger)(a_\mathbf{R}+a_\mathbf{R}^\dagger)$$

where $H_0=\hbar\omega_0\sum_\mathbf{R} a_\mathbf{R}^\dagger a_\mathbf{R}$. The bosonic operators can be converted to wave-vector/momentum space via $a_\mathbf{R}=\mathcal{N}^{-1/2}\sum_\mathbf{q}\exp(i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{R})a_\mathbf{q}$ where $\mathcal{N}$ is a normalisation factor (number of unit cells). Once I have the Hamiltonian in this representation I can easily work out the dispersion etc. (which is trivial for this system but introducing interactions makes it more complicated). However I don't know how to represent $\eta$ in this space. Now I am stuck.

Any suggestions, references and help would be great :)

Comment: Just to be clear I mean that $\omega_0$ changes randomly from  each location $\mathbf{R}$ according to some distribution, not that at each location there is some sort of 'blur' of values.

Comment: Oh and if people need to choose a distribution to answer the question I would suggest Gaussian, but I don't really mind. To make physical sense it just has to be bunched up around the value $\omega_0$ and die off quickly either side

Comment: What are you trying to take the FT of?   You say you want to make a transform into momentum space, but aren't you already there?  Your Hamiltonian already is a function of momentum.  I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully make things clearer. Basically I have a real space representation of the Hamiltoniain and I want to go into reciprocal space. I don't know how to treat $\eta$

Comment: @JanLalinsky has the right answer.  Your Hamiltonian is already diagonal (in position basis).  That is, you already know all the eigenvectors.  There's no point in changing basis. The eigenvalues are distributed. You can calculate a physical property as a function of $\omega$.  Many properties simply add incoherently, so you can just average using $\eta$ as a weighting function.  However if there is coherent interactions (for example, interference) you might be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no interaction between the parts of your lattice, the response of the total system is sum of responses of the individual parts. These parts are harmonic oscillators, whose response function is well-known. If these have many different frequencies, the total system will have response function with peaks at these frequencies. No need for boson operators or momentum space.

If there is interaction between the parts, the system will have different eigenfrequencies from those of the oscillators forming the lattice. These can be found from the resulting new Hamiltonian function (operator). One way could be the method you suggest, but the procedure will need to use the interaction Hamiltonian.

In any case, search linear response theory.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the case that the eigenfrequecies will depend on how the frequencies are distributed among the oscillators?  Each realization of the set of frequencies will have different eigenfrequencies.  If so, it suggests the need for an ensemble average.

Comment: If the oscillators interact with each other, the eigenfrequencies of the system will depend on both the original frequencies and the strengths of harmonic interactions. Of course, average over probability distribution may be used to account for many random frequencies of the oscillators, if one wants to do so.

Comment: ok, so the OP question does not have a definitive answer (outside of averaging) as the spatial distribution of frequencies and interactions is not known.  We know only that the frequencies are a random variable function of position.

Comment: Actually, re-reading the original post, we know that the dipoles are non-interacting, which makes the transformation to $k$-space dubious, as you point out.

Comment: Ok maybe I oversimplified the problem. In reality I have a system of interacting nanoparticles described by the non-interacting Hamiltonian shown plus a nearest-neighbour interaction term (described in detail here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.7796v1.pdf). Basically I just want to know how the game changes when my natural frequency $\omega_0$ can take on a random variable (from a distribution) for each nanoparticle. I want to know how much this disorder smears out the energy spectrum (dispersion) so I know what features will be resolvable.

Comment: @Tom that seems like an involved investigation. It reminds me of searching for eigenvalues of random matrices (in this case, with random diagonal and some off-diagonal terms). Similar calculations of spectra of random matrices were done in nuclear physics, I think.

Comment: Definitely involved, that's why I originally posted as simple a question as I could think to be sign posted along the right path, but there's a lot of reading and searching yet to be done.